# Spring Boot: Read username value of Bearer Token Authorization from Postman request

Tags: spring-boot, postman, bearer-token

I am trying to get the username using the method **getRemoteUser()** of **HttpServletRequest**. This works fine when the request is initiated through the web application. However when the request is initiated through Postman. The value of getRemoteUser() is null.

I found out that the only way to get the username would be though the Bearer token used as Authorization in Postman.

I need the username to call another REST API which takes username in payload. I even tried to pass the Authorization Bearer token to the REST API if it can return the required result. But since it is expecting the username in payload this did not work.

Can anyone help me extract username from Bearer Token?

Comment: Can you try `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();`? What's the output when you do it for requests from Postman?

Comment: Thanks @FelixSchildmann, your suggestion worked. Can you post your suggestion as an answer :)

Comment: posted it as answer, can you accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()` instead to get the username of the authenticated user